# Z-index on siblings elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, z-index, siblings

I am creating an hidden menu in jquery. The idea is to put it in the front of all the other elements when it is selected. The other elements are basically siblings of the menu. I am using  'object.css('z-index')' to get the effect. It works when in my code I use the specific classes of the siblings. But When I keep it more  general using 'object.siblings().css()', I have no effect. I would like not to use classes to keep the codes as more general as possible. All the element are positioned already.

The HTML structure look like this.

```
<html>
  <body>  
    <div class="nav">  
    </div>
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="container">  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

where '.nav' is my hidden menu
Below in Jquery where I apply the z-indexes:

```
label.on('click', function () {
if (sbar.css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
    $('.button').animate({'right': '+=201px'}, 200);
    $('.sidebar').css({'visibility':'visible'})
    wrapper.css('z-index', '1');
    $('.container').css('z-index', '-1');
    $('.top').css('z-index', '-1');
} else  {  
    $('.button').animate({'right': '-=201px'},200);
    $('.sidebar').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
    wrapper.css('z-index', 'initial');
    $('.container').css('z-index', 'initial');    
    $('.top').css('z-index', 'initial');
```

Like these the codes are making their job on the z-index. But if I change the classes $('.container') and $(.top') and merge the codes in the '.sibling' selector such as:

`wrapper.siblings().css({'z-index': '-1'});`

It simply does not work.Any suggestions on what I might have done wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

```
wrapper.siblings().css("z-index", "-1" );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your solution, but for some reasons it did not work. I decided to rewrite the codes later to use a different approach.